# Site analytics looks broken: "responsiveness" and "yandex.rug.stackexchange.com"

Tags: bug, design, responsive-design, site-analytics

I noticed some problems on the site analytics page. I saw these problems on [ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/site-analytics), but they could happen anywhere.

First of all, the page is "responsive", which apparently means that as the browser window gets smaller, everything is squished together so that you can't read any of it:

[image]

Another thing I noticed is that some of the labels on the pie chart are cut off and sometimes everything lines up perfectly and you start to think that yandex.rug.stackexchange.com is a real site (instead of it just being one slice labeled "**yandex.ru**" and another labeled "engineerin**g.stackexchange.com**"):

[image]

(Just to be clear, "workplace.stackexchange.com" is part of bug #1 above, as is the divider.)

Comment: Rug Stack Exchange. It's about time we got into the flooring business.